# Replace %20 with empty string using REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: sql, mysql, regex, regexp-replace

A table "employee" has a column "content" that contains long HTML text. The HTML text also contains multiple *href* links inside the anchor tag. I want to replace all the %20 present in the *href* link with an empty string.

**Note that any %20 occurrence that is not in the href link (but in the HTML text), should not be considered for the replacement.**

For eg, consider the following text in the "content" field:

```
<h2><strong>1. Introduction</strong></h2>\n  %20AND%20The tutorial illustrates how to <strong>create a Web %20AND%20Application with Java. 
<a href=\"https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework.data%20a:spring-da%20ta-jpa\">the <em>spring-data-jp%20a</em> \n 
<a href=\"https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework.data%20a:spring-da%21ta-jpa\">the <em>spring-data-jp%20a</em>
```

The expected output is:

```
<h2><strong>1. Introduction</strong></h2>\n  %20AND%20The tutorial illustrates how to <strong>create a Web %20AND%20Application with Java. 
<a href=\"https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework.dataa:spring-data-jpa\">the <em>spring-data-jp%20a</em> \n 
<a href=\"https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework.dataa:spring-da%21ta-jpa\">the <em>spring-data-jp%20a</em>
```

Explanation:

- In the first line, none of the %20 was replaced as they were not a part of any href link.
- In the second and third lines, both the %20 in the href link `data%20a:spring-da%20ta-jpa` we replaced with empty string. Note that %20 was not replaced in this part `<em>spring-data-jp%20a</em>` as it was not a part of the href link.

I think [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) will be helpful in this case. Can anyone help me form appropriate query for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at distinguishing "inside" and "outside" context for matches. Why do you even have `%20` outside URLs? It has no meaning in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

```
with data (s) as (values
  ('<h2><strong>1. Intro/h2>\n  %20AND%20The tuate a Webion'), 
  ('<a href=\.data%20a:spa%20ta-jpa\"><em>spata-jp%20a</em>')
)
select replace(s,
               regexp_substr(s,'^\<[^>]+'),
               replace(regexp_substr(s,'^\<[^>]+'),'%20','*')
       )
from   data
```

1. extract the substring between < and >
2. in this extract replace %20 by * (or space)
3. replace the extracted substr (1) by the modified (2)